# Using hibernate with bcache

Tags: hibernate, bcache

I have writethrough bcache working on Debian Sid with an underlying LUKS + LVM. My swap partition (already present) is lying unused as an LVM volume.

I know that I am supposed to stop bcache before hibernation (suspend to disk), and resume bcache after resume (cannot be active during either).

How exactly do I ensure that? Are there are any pre- and post- scripts for this? If so, how should stop and restart bcache. All that echo n > /sys ... business can go remarkably awry if one does not know what one is doing.

Getting hibernation working is the last pending thing after the install.